# I couldn't read cursive letter

Tags: meaning

I'm high school student in South Korea. I applied for volunteer letter translation work. So I have to translate it into Korean. But I have trouble with reading cursive letter. Because I don't have experience related with it. I tried to do my best but I couldn't read it fully. So I want to read it in print.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: This question isn't really asking about English; it's simply a request to interpret careless penmanship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> Purity greets you in the name of Jesus Christ. She tells you that she is fine with her family and hopes that you too you're okay. She says the Lord is good to her family because her mother got a new baby. Purity says she loves school and is learning well. She asks you to pray for her so that she can continue performing well in school. She informs you that the compassion project is the best place to be. She says she learns socio-emotional, cognitive, physical and spiritual lessons. She is glad because she received the letter you sent her. She informs you that she is fine and healthy. She tells you that she spends her day to day time at school learning and playing with friends after school. She informs you that she loves attending church, school and the compassion project. Purity tells you her favourite food is rice and meat stew. She asks you which is your favourite food. She says that her mother prepares a lovely food which she enjoys eating. She tells you that God is so good to her and that she loves Him so much. Purity would like to take this opportunity to thank you so much for your letters, gifts and support and tells you that together with her family she will continue praying for you. She asks the lord God to bless you so much.

I didn't fix any of the grammatical errors. And, by the way, this site is for people learning to speak English and it isn't really for asking for help with problems like this.

Comment: Thank you!! I really really appreciate it!!  you are my hero!  I couldn't forget your help!   ps. How can I find Q/A site for something like it? Could you recommend one?

Comment: @KawaH I honestly have no idea if there are any Q/A sites for deciphering handwritten text, sorry.

Comment: Try Yahoo! Answers, which will let you ask a question about nearly anything.

Comment: @Phil14 - I appreciate your helpful spirit, but please be careful about [feeding the bears](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears). At the very least, we should have asked the O.P. to narrow the letter down by pointing out the more indecipherable parts, so that the community wouldn't need to transcribe the whole thing.